# which control is clicked in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to perform an action in datagridview, like calculation. When the user type Amount in textbox, I want to calculate its instalment. The problem is that I have also a combobox in my datagridview. When I select something from the grid combobox, I get exception in my code, so I want to stop to perform my calculation when user click on combobox.
How can I know if the user have clicked or select something from combobox?

```
private void prol04DataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
     TextBox tx = e.Control as TextBox;
     // Below line i am geting error Because i select combobox in datagrid
     DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = DataGridViewTextBoxCell)prol04DataGridView.CurrentCell;
     if (tx != null && cell.OwningColumn == prol04DataGridView.Columns[5])
     {
         tx.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(tx_TextChanged);
         tx.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tx_TextChanged);
     }             
}
```

So how can I find on which control on datagrid have the user performed an action?

Comment: The fact that `tx == null` should hint that it isn't a `TextBox` cell.

Comment: @Steve execption is `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the same logic used to cast the e.Control to a TextBox also to the CurrentCell

```
 TextBox tx = e.Control as TextBox;
 DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = prol04DataGridView.CurrentCell as DataGridViewTextBoxCell;
 if (tx != null && cell != null && cell.OwningColumn == prol04DataGridView.Columns[5])
 {
       tx.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(tx_TextChanged);
       tx.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tx_TextChanged);

 }
```

Comment: I've upvoted since this is correct, but might I suggest adding in that one can get the current cell's column index or owningcolumn, and use that to check that you are in the correct column. Useful if (for example) you have to textbox columns and only want to work on one.

Comment: Thanks its work for me  i have upvote your answer :) But if i want to know which type of cell is clicked how can i know .